# HTML5 getUserMedia - Disable Microphone Feedback

Tags: html

Seems that this is a big problem and I couldnt find anything in the documentations, but how do I disable the microphone feebdack? I know there is an option to disable individual tracks, etc .. but nothing related to output.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue and this is how I got to disable the microphone feedback in my web app (my web app is recording the mic with Matt Diamond recorder js).
First I realized I had in my code something that was telling the app to produce the feedback :)

```
input.connect(audio_context.destination);
```

So I just commented this line ... but still got the feedback on my Jabra headset but no more feedback when I use external speakers (while still using the Jabra headset mic).

I then realized there was a setting in my Windows 8.1 control panel > sound > playback tab > properties for the Jabra device I use. The setting is called **sidetone** and once I got this setting to 0 I could record without any feedback with my headset.
You also need to make sure your microphone is not in "Listen to this device" mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
try {
    yourSteam.getTracks()[0].stop();
} catch (ex) {
    // This fails in some older versions of chrome. Nothing we can do about it.
}
```

I got that code from https://github.com/saebekassebil/microphone-stream and it is the only way that works for me.